# How can I display a section of a table depending on the ID of the page?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Basically I have a view which contains a template for 3 different pages. However 2 of these pages require different contents in the table compared to the first. My first thought was to have an IF statement within the table which checked to see what the ID of the page was and therefore display this section of the table if the result was true. However, the view does not pick up on the ID of the page and just always leaves the section of the table out. My second idea was to Use Html.RenderPartial and render the table depending on the ID but this did not work either. Does anybody know how to get the ID of the page and then use it to create an if statement without creating 3 different but almost identical views? I have my code below:

```
   <% Using Html.BeginForm("SubmitEmailTemplate", "Maintenance", Nothing, FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "formEditTemplate"})%>
    <%: Html.Hidden("txtEmailTemplateID", Model.EmailTemplate.EmailTemplateID)%>
    <%: Html.Hidden("txtEmailTemplateType", Model.EmailTemplate.EmailTemplateType)%>

     <%: MasterPageHelpers.ContainerStart("wid1", "Email Templates", 16)%>

    <table class="layout-standard-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="prompt">Subject</td>
            <td class="details"><%: Html.TextBox("txtSubject", Model.EmailTemplate.Subject)%><button type="button" onclick="DialogMerge('txtSubject')" title="Insert Merge Fields"><img src="<%: Url.Content("~/content/img/icons/plus.png")%>" alt="" /> Insert Merge Fields</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="prompt">Body</td>
              <td><%: Html.TextArea("txtBodyText", Model.EmailTemplate.BodyText)%> <button type="button" onclick="DialogMerge('txtBodyText')" title="Insert Merge Fields"><img src="<%:Url.Content("~/content/img/icons/plus.png")%>" alt="" /> Insert Merge Fields</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="SaveTemplate()" title="OK"><img src="<%: Url.Content("~/content/img/icons/tick.png")%>" alt="" /> OK</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="NavigateBack()" title="Cancel"><img src="<%: Url.Content("~/content/img/icons/cross.png")%>" alt="" /> Cancel</button>
    </div>

    <div id="divInsertMergeFieldSubject" style="display:none"">
        <table class="layout-standard-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Merge Field</td>
                <td>Description</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a onclick='InsertMergeField("Owner")'>Owner</a></td>
                <td>The Owner of the ticket</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a onclick='InsertMergeField("Client")'>Client</a></td>
                <td>The Client</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a onclick='InsertMergeField("Description")'>Description</a></td>
                <td>The Decription of the ticket</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a onclick='InsertMergeField("Notes")'>Notes</a></td>
                <td>The Notes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a onclick='InsertMergeField("Classification")'>Classification</a></td>
                <td>The Classification of the ticket</td>
            </tr>     
<!-- The IF statement -->    
                    <% If Model.EmailTemplate.EmailTemplateID = 2 Or 3 Then%>
                <tr>
                <td><a onclick='InsertMergeField("ResponseBy")'>Response By</a></td>
                <td>The person who responded to the ticket</td>
            </tr>      
                <% End If%>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. For some reason the IF did not like the fact that there was an OR. I am not sure why. The way around it I found was to (although it is bad practice), duplicate the table row.

EDIT: Found an even better fix. You must repeat the ID twice in order for it to take the IF into account. Code is below:

```
 <% If Model.EmailTemplate.EmailTemplateType = 2 Or Model.EmailTemplate.EmailTemplateType = 3 Then%>
            <tr>     
                <td><a onclick='InsertMergeField("ResponseBy")'>Response By</a></td>
                <td>The person who responded to the ticket</td>
            </tr>   
                 <% End If%>
```